Logic behind the ATX power switch
I am designing an ATX-style motherboard. I have been messing with the 6502 processor, made a working computer, and now want to challenge myself with designing a 6502-based ATX-compatible board.
I'm having trouble on how to control the switch input. Currently, I have a setup that uses a toggle with my board, much like the older AT-style setups. And since I feel that leaving the switch on for an indefinite amount of time isn't healthy for the PSU, I would like to make a more modern approach.
I understand the switch itself is a simple N/O MOM switch, but what controls the Logic? My first thought was a simple T Flip-Flop, but while that would work on the power-on, that would also turn the board off instantly, which is not how a usual computer works. Usually, taping the power switch while on just tells the OS to shut down, while holding it for a predetermined amount of seconds will do a full power-off.
Is there a special chip that controls the power button? Or is it all software based through the BIOS/OS? And if it's software based, what would the hardware side look like? I know the switch bridges the +5VSB of the PSU to GND, I don't know if there is anything else in-between that.
The closest I have found to this while Googling is "When the power button is pressed, it sends voltage to the logic circuit". I'm here looking for what and how that logic circuit works.

I think this was part of the mainboard chipset/southbridge. Ask retrocomputing?

@greybeard That's not a bad idea. I didn't even know about there being a retrocomputing variant of stack exchange until your comment; goes to show how often I'm here :P I put this question here because in my searches I was brought to the Electronics stack exchange a few times, and it felt fitting for the area.
Anyways, posting it to RetroComputing would absolutely give me some 6502-specific results, however I'm also more interested in a generic not-CPU dependent answer, which I thing I can achieve here. I will keep RetroComputing in mind for other questions, thanks! :)

As said, this is part of the chipset. There's (probably) a whole microcontroller core in there running it's own firmware allowing them all the logic they want. So a discrete microcontroller would be your cleanest option.

Are you asking how to design a circuit like this? or asking how an ATX circuit works?

leaving the switch on for an indefinite amount of time isn't healthy for the PSU ... the logic circuit would do the same thing ... the only difference is that the logic circuit is able to do a software controlled powerdown
